# Vertical centering of text of select-element

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I've created a small codepen to test how to align span,div, input and select elements evenly inside a container. After alot of trial and error it's working across Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QJQaVX

But the problem now is the select-box. The text which shows the actual selection is moved to bottom-line of the inner text. This is also visible in the inspector. Surprisingly Edge is showing the expected behaviour and centers the text. But Chrome and Firefox won't. 
I've tried setting line-height without success. Even `display:flex` is not changing anything.

Is there any proper solution for this problem?

Comment: Probably because you have given a `height` to the `option`. I tried to remove it and it does center.

Comment: Correct, it looks like your height option is cause problems. I'd recommend removing the Option out of the CSS rule which gives it a height.

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. I've removed `option` from the selector and still get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long trial&error and combining different answers from Stackoverflow, I've found a solution which is working for me on IE11, Edge, Chrome and FF.
All elements have the same height in all browsers. All elements use font-size from the parent element. Also no need for normalize.css or anything. 
I've disabled the dropdown-arrow on select, but it's not affecting the result if enabled.
Only difference is on the text-indent at the select box. In IE11 and Edge, the text is starting with a small padding from left side. On Firefox I was able to solve the issue.

https://codepen.io/auskennfuchs/pen/xMqVgG

```
.formcontrol {
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: @form-height;
}

input, select, button {
  border: 0;  
  height: @form-height;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Of course the use of flexbox is much easier but there are some situation where flexbox isn't helping, e.g. 2 column responsive layout with form elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the code for you and play with the padding & content box. this will work across all the browser.

Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/summitpattel/pen/RqQqBG)

```
<div id="container1">
    <input id="textbox" type="text" value="Test" />
    <span>TestText</span>
    <div>TestText</div>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option>Test</option>
    </select>
</div>


#container1 input[type="text"], 
#container1 select, 
#container1 span, 
#container1 div {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This is working but I have one issue with it. The positioning inside the container is only working with margin. When I change to margin to 0 and use padding of the container again, the select box is moved up slightly. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrQjWZ 
I don't get why this has to be so difficult or why the form-controls behave differently than any other element :-(

Comment: This issue can resolve with using flex property and also we have to use px for line height and height. Check out this  [codepen](https://codepen.io/summitpattel/pen/RqQqBG)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and found that the **font-family: inherit** in input, select, textarea is extra.

> **Inherits** this property from its parent element. The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

From: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

Your input, select,div are already in the container class, the font-family is inherited by default.

You could modfiy your code as follow.

HTML.

```
 <div class="container">
   <input type="text" value="TestText">
   <span>TestText</span>
   <div>TestText</div>
   <select>
     <option>Test</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

CSS.

```
input, select, span, div { 
line-height: 1.15em;
height: 1.15em;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[image: Result]